# WordPress admin-ajax slow/issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress, admin-ajax

I've noticed in our hosting's snapshot that our admin ajax has been very slow.

The example http query below took over 191seconds! also this fired every couple of minutes..
/admin-ajax.php?action=oembed-cache&post=814

apart from that just the normal admin-ajax.php takes about 15seconds. Sometimes spikes to 45seconds.

This leads to some get requests for our products to take 45seconds.

Any ideas what the cause/fix to this might be, or at least where I should look into next? Query monitor is not showing any errors only some minor notices and nothing in debug.log.

Thanks

Comment: Some time the wordpress admin ajax blocked by server please check if the same happen to you

Comment: Ajax is not blocked on my server, it's even whitelisted within wordfence